# What is meaning of step in loss graph

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I find some paper (Resnet paper) has the graph as follows:
[image]

As you see, the loss gradually decreases when iterations increasing. But at some point (red arrow), the loss rapid decrease (as a step). What is this point? Is it changing learning rate point? Thanks all

Comment: Please link [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf). I think the learning rate got decreased on that point, but i'm not sure as it isn't exactly referenced in the paper.

Comment: Yes. This is the paper that I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they changed the learning rate at that point. It could be a learning rate schedule, which means decrease the learning rate by a factor every X iterations, or it could be another policy like decrease the learning rate when a plateau in the loss is detected.